# SharePoint List Size Limit For Importing into Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, sharepoint

What is the largest SharePoint list you can import into Azure Data Factory ? And how do you tell how big a current SharePoint List is ? Looking online and cant really find the answers I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get upto 5000 items for a single query.

When you design the pipeline , you provide the query as part of the copy activity properties.

If the query is designed to pull more than 5000 items - it will fail. You can pull as many items in batches of 5000.